# Assigning checkbox values to variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, nested-checkboxes

I've got a list of possible checkboxes and the user can select up to three options.  What I'm struggling with is how to recognize which boxes are checked, and then assign them to variables (to send in a later ajax call).  So far the code I've written seems to just take the first three checkbox values regardless of whether they are checked or not and use those in my ajax call.  Please help me figure out where I've gone wrong.

Here's my HTML:

```
<ul id="Names" class="stateNames">
    <li>Alabama
        <ul class="airports">
            <li><input type="checkbox" class="destination"/> Birmingham, AL</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" class="destination"/> Huntsville, AL</li>
        </ul>
    <li>Alaska
        <ul class="airports">
            <li><input type="checkbox" class="destination"/> Anchorage, AK</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" class="destination"/> Fairbanks, AK</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" class="destination"/> Juneau, AK</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<input type="button" onclick="clickHandler()" value="Submit" />
```

Here's my javascript/jquery:

```
function clickHandler() {
endLocDest1 = "";
endLocDest2 = "";
endLocDest3 = "";

for(i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName('destination').length; i++) {
    if (document.getElementsByClassName('destination')[i].checked) {
        endLocDest1 = document.getElementsByClassName('destination')[0].value;
        endLocDest2 = document.getElementsByClassName('destination')[1].value;
        endLocDest3 = document.getElementsByClassName('destination')[2].value;
    }
    alert(endLocDest1 + endLocDest2 + endLocDest3);
};
}
```

I've also put this code into a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6ywm1n6h/3/ (which currently doesn't return anything).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try:  
var destBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("destination");  
for (i = 0; i < destBoxes.length; i += 1) {  
    alert(destBoxes[i].value;  
}

Comment: Is the limitation of up to 3 per state or in total?

Comment: @haim770 it's 3 in total (could be a single state, or multiple states)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your jsfiddle, you had jQuery turned on, assuming that, try using ...

```
$(".destination:checked")
```

Which will return all checked; you can use this as an array and determine which are clicked.

**EDIT:**
You can assign this to a variable, say ...

```
var checked_values = $(".destination:checked");
```

... then loop through and do what you need.

```
for (var i=0,len=checked_values.length; i<len; i++) {
  console.log(checked_values[i].attr("id"));
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate on what needs to come after this?  I'm a bit new to javascript and jquery.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is wrapped in `<form>` and `</form>` then checked inputs will be sent automatically when form is submitted (normaly or AJAX'ed). Your mistake is that you do not set `name`s nor `value`s to your checkboxes. Try:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="airport[alabama][]" value="Birmingham">
<input type="checkbox" name="airport[alabama][]" value="Huntsville">
<input type="checkbox" name="airport[alaska][]" value="Anchorage">
<input type="checkbox" name="airport[alaska][]" value="Fairbanks">
```

and see `print_r($_POST)` or `print_r($_GET)` (depending on your form method) in page which receives form submission.

Comment: I'm actually not using the <form> element on purpose because I have to make a custom array of JSON data with a bunch of other nested info before I send the ajax call (I took out the other info to simplify the question). Any other suggestions?

Comment: You do not need other suggestions, because solution is already posted here. To summarize: set `value` attributes to checkboxes and select them with `$(':checked')`.